# pop variable in while loop will not print after completed

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop

I am attempting to pop all of the greetings in the list greetings into the sent_messages list, however when I print sent_messages I only receive the last greeting, while I want to get all of them.

```
greetings = ['greetings', 'hello', 'good day', 'good evening']


while greetings:
    print(greetings[0])
    sent_messages = greetings.pop(0)

print(sent_messages)
```

Comment: Well, yes, `pop` returns *one* element, which you assign to `sent_messages`. `sent_messages` isn't a list and you're not even attempting to treat it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pop method remove the element at the specifyed index from the list and return it.

Your code is overriding the value of `sent_message` each time the while loop loops. So only receiving the last greeting is perfectly normal.

this modified exemple of your code could help you to convince yourself that pop indeed work as intended.

```py
greetings = ['greetings', 'hello', 'good day', 'good evening']


while greetings:
    print(greetings[0])
    sent_messages = greetings.pop(0)
    print(sent_messages)
```

you said that you wanted to put the poped element in the sent_messages list here is a code that do what you were expecting :

```py
greetings = ['greetings', 'hello', 'good day', 'good evening']
sent_messages = []

while greetings:
    print(greetings[0])
    sent_messages.append(greetings.pop(0))
    
print(sent_messages)
```

we create `sent_messages` as a list before using it and use the `.append` method to add them at the end of list.